# Swift changes the type of parameter of a block, which is also the parameter of Objective-C method

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks

I have an Objective-C class that has methods with block parameters:

```
+ (void)getCurrentUserInfoWithToken:(NSString*)token completionHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary* userData))handler
```

As you can see, the block has NSDictionary parameter. But when I try to cast this method in swift, it gives an error: "'[NSObject : AnyObject]' is not identical to 'NSDictionary'". Here's my Swift code:

```
ClockfaceAPI.getCurrentUserInfoWithToken(token, completionHandler: {
            (userData : NSDictionary!) in
            // block implementation goes here
})
```

And I have no idea how to solve it =/

Comment: See the _Dictionaries_ section of [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C: Working with Cocoa Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_42), which discusses the fact that `NSDictionary` references are replaced with `[NSObject: AnyObject]` Swift dictionaries. As DPlusV points out, you should just use this Swift dictionary and the Swift dictionary patterns rather than the `NSDictionary` patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes sense, as your NSDictionary* gets interpreted as [NSObject:AnyObject]

You don't have to specify the type. E.g. just saying `userData` without `: NSDictionary!` will work fine. Swift will automatically infer the type based on the declaration.

```
ClockFaceAPI.getCurrentUserInfoWithToken(token, completionHandler: { (dict) -> Void in
    for (k, v) in dict {
        println(k)
        println(v)
    }
})
```

Comment: but when I do so and then call dict.objectForKey, it says that [NSObject:AnyObject] doesn't have such method =/

Comment: Don't use `objectForKey`. Use the subscript syntax, e.g. `dict[key]` instead of `dict.objectForKey(key)`.